# How to Get the MongoDB Connection String to Work Around Downed Nodes?

Tags: php, mongodb, replication

I am running some tests on a test a cluster I have set up.  Right now, I have a three node cluster with one master, one slave and one arbiter.

I have a connection string like

```
mongodb://admin:pass@the_slave_node,the_master_node
```

I was under the impression that one of the features inherent in the connection string was that supplying more than one host would introduce a certain degree of resiliency on the client side.  I was expecting that when I took down the_slave_node that the php driver should have moved on and try connecting to the_master_node, however this doesn't seem to be the case and instead I get the error:

```
The MongoCursor object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor
```

I know that MongoClient is responsible for making the initial connections, and indeed it is that way in the code.  So this error is an indication to me that the MongoClient didn't connect properly and I didn't implement correct error checking.  However that is a different issue --

How do I guarantee that the MongoClient will connect to at least one of the hosts in the hosts csv in the event at least one host is up and some hosts are down?

Thank you

Comment: that's not a connection problem, that means you have an error in your code, to be more specific if it cannot connect it will throw an exception saying no candidate servers found, I always get this error when I use the extension wrong

Comment: So I did more experimenting and I think I'm a little closer to the problem.  I changed the connection string to only point to the_master_node (I removed the_slave_node) so now the connection string only has one host.  When both slave and master are up, it works great.  When I take down the slave, then it begins to fail, sometimes giving me the no candidate error, sometimes giving me a 502 bad gateway.  To be clear, it is the master in the connection string, not the slave.  So I do not understand why taking down the slave would cause this cascade of errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm what driver version is this? Also what is yuor read preference?

Comment: driver version 1.3.3 and mongodb server version 2.4.5

Comment: I am pretty sure this should work on 1.4.x, I haven't actually got my server with me to try, can you upgrade?

Comment: read preference is secondary_preferred, however I tried multiple times with and without that read preference with no difference in results.  My understanding is that the slave_prefferered wouldn't fault reading from the master anyway if no slaves are available.

Comment: I will upgrade and then report back

Comment: Yeah if it secondary preferred, thought it might be secondary only, was a long shot

Comment: brilliant!  now it works exactly as expected, in both forms of the connection string (master only and slave,master), very nice, very nice.  Pages load a tad slower, however I am sure that is an issue with my needing to fine tune timeouts and whatnot, at any rate, when your db nodes are down I guess it is a reasonable to expect things will also be slower.  Thank you very much sir.

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

> The MongoCursor object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor

This error should only ever happen if you are constructing your own MongoCursor and overwriting its constructor.

This would happen with for example

```
class MyCursor extends MongoCursor {
    function __construct(MongoClient $connection, $ns , array $query = array(), array $fields = array()) {
    /* Do some work, forgetting to call parent::__construct(....); */
    }
}
```

If you are not extending any of the classes, then this error is definetly a bug and you should [report it please](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP) :)

> How do I guarantee that the MongoClient will connect to at least one of the hosts

Put at least one member of each datacenter into your seed list.
Tune the various timeout options, and plan for the case when the primary is down (e.g. which servers should you be reading from instead?)

I suspect you may have forgotten to specify the "replicaSet" option, since you mention your connection string without it?

The following snippet is what I recommend (adapt at will), especially when you require full consistency when possible (e.g. always reading from a primary).

```
<?php
$seedList = "hostname1:port,hostname2:port";
$options  = array(
    // If the server is down, don't wait forever
    "connectTimeoutMS"   => 500,
    // When the server goes down in the middle of operation, don't wait forever
    "socketTimeoutMS"    => 5000, 
    "replicaSet"         => "ReplicasetName",
    "w"                  => "majority",
    // Don't wait forever for majority write acknowledgment
    "wtimeout"           => 500,
    // When the primary goes down, allow reading from secondaries
    "readPreference"     => MongoClient::RP_PRIMARY_PREFERRED,
    // When the primary is down, prioritize reading from our local datacenter
    // If that datacenter is down too, fallback to any server available
    "readPreferenceTags" => array("dc:is", ""),
);
try {
    $mc = new MongoClient($seedList, $options);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    /* I always have some sort of "Skynet"/"Ground control"/"Houston, We have a problem" system to automate taking down (or put into automated maintenance mode) my webservers in case of epic failure.. */
    automateMaintenance($e);
}
```